# Model Error: It appears that build process was unable to locate some Utility(e.g. make,compiler,linker, etc.)

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I am new to S-Functions and Real TIme WorkShop. The S-Function has been created using an Embedded Matlab Function. The S-Function Works fine, but when i try to build the same, i get the following error report:

**It appears that the build process was unable to locate some utility (e.g. make, compiler, linker, etc.). Please verify your path and tool environment variables are correct. You should be able to execute the make command: .\Radius_S_func2.bat at an MS DOS Command Prompt in the directory: C:\Users\skaushik\Desktop\Matlab Models\WIP\TESTs\Sfunc_2\Radius_S_func2_Source Currently, this generates the following error:
C:\Users\skaushik\Desktop\Matlab Models\WIP\TESTs\Sfunc_2\Radius_S_func2_Source>set MATLAB=C:\MATLAB\R2010b
C:\Users\skaushik\Desktop\Matlab Models\WIP\TESTs\Sfunc_2\Radius_S_func2_Source>.......\u_Utils\Build\make -f Radius_S_func2.mk GENERATE_REPORT=0 INCLUDE_MDL_TERMINATE_FCN=0 COMBINE_OUTPUT_UPDATE_FCNS=1 MAT_FILE=0 MULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 INTEGER_CODE=0 PORTABLE_WORDSIZES=0 GENERATE_ERT_S_FUNCTION=0 GENERATE_ASAP2=0 EXT_MODE=0 EXTMODE_STATIC_ALLOC=0 EXTMODE_STATIC_ALLOC_SIZE=1000000 EXTMODE_TRANSPORT=0 TMW_EXTMODE_TESTING=0 MODELLIB=Radius_S_func2lib.lib RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR=.. MODELREF_TARGET_TYPE=NONE OPTS="-DRT -DUSE_RTMODEL -DERT" The system cannot find the path specified.**

PLease guide me how to understand the error, so i can take care of it myself.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The build target was not specified therefore matlab gave the above mentioned error. To resolve this one should specify the build environment for a specific target.